# Updating JScript intellisense hangs VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have a web application and whenever I load it in VS 2010 RTM, the left hand corner of VS says "updating JScript intellisense" which never completes.  When I click anywhere in the editor (becuase the solution has finished loading), I see a balloon on the right hand corner saying Visual studio is performing an internal operation...) and ultimately I have to end the VS process. Very frustrating..
I went ahead and disabled JScript intellisense as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1.aspx) and that didn't help.
Anybody has any clue in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted my machine and It resolved the problem. :-(

Comment: Very annoying, just had the exact same issue. Force quit ~5 times before I finally restarted the computer, all working now :) 

I think this may come down to some of the plugins I installed, but I'm not sure which ones...

Answer (score 3):

Pin open your Output window to get specific information on what Visual Studio is doing. Chances are it is parsing js file links in your webpage, including master page and trying to download these files over the network or encountering an error trying make intellisense of them all. Try commenting out your javascript links, using local copies instead of remote, or attempt to resolve the specific errors. [More info here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629101513/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/18/jscript-intellisense-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late answering this question, but I found a way to disable JScript Intellisense. Following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1.aspx , in the "Text Editor" options, select JScript. In the "General" options, deselect the checkboxes saying "Auto list members" and "Parameter Information". It worked fine for me.